# Can't see my mySql projects in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, wampserver

So I recently installed **Wamp server** and whenever I create any database on MySql workbench, it shows on **Mariadb** instead of **mysql**. Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: WAMPServer (modern versions) installs a mariaDB and a MySQL DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMPServer 3 installs both MySQL and mariaDB.

Also, recent versions have used non standard ports for these 2 database servers in order that those that have installed a MySQL instance for some other reason and forgotten to remove it dont get the MySQL Server from WAMPServer confused with another instance.

So Mysql uses port 3308 and mariaDB uses port 3307.

It sounds like you have connected MySQLWorkbench to port 3307, or at least you have connected workbench to the mariaDB instance and not the MySQL instance. That is a little dangerous as mariaDB is not completely compatable with MySQL Workbench and when you connect the 2 it should give you a warning mesage.

Check the menus to see which port is being used by which server instance.

Left click the wampserver icon in the system tray to see this

Check the blue link that says `Port used by ....`

This is MySQL using port 3308

[image: This is MySQL]

And this is mariaDB using port 3307

[image: This is mariaDB]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you got two databases installed. You can just use MySql workbench instead any database given by wamp together with other services on wamp

Comment: I think wamp gives a MySql server not mariaDb

Comment: Modern WAMPServer installs both MySQL and mariaDB